# Show modal notifications in React Native when app is background or killed. Similar to Whatsapp Call notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement notifications in React-Native app. My notifications are pretty similar to WhatsApp call. No matter the app is open or closed, your phone is locked or not, it shows the notification that someone is calling. I searched about it a lot and it's been days scratching my head. If Any can give me a direction, that will be helpful.

I have been using FCM, it shows badge notification but can't show a custom modal or anything.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If so, do you mind sharing with us?

Comment: Yes, I searched around for this and I found out that we have to use the native call feature. That allows having accept and reject options. Whereas having customized options is not possible in apple. Even that works in Android but not in iOS.
Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that out.